# How many times should I/could I edit my question?

Tags: discussion, editing

My question has a fairly large [edit history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/49066/revisions) already, some major, some minor, but the original question has changed into another altogether. However, the original theatrics were unfortunately lost, but I do intend to (possibly) reiterate then into the new question. To be up-front: I'd like to do that merely for entertainment, and it isn't likely to improve or hinder the original meaning of the question.

Should I? As I said, it's merely for a bit of fun, so it's not all that important.

Comment: You've mentioned "[theatrics](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/theatrics)" a few times. I don't think I understand what meaning of it that you intend. What do you mean by "theatrics"?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie for example writing the question from the POV of one of the characters, rather than the player.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, that's a bad idea. It's often hard enough to help real people; roleplaying a pretend person asking for help from real people who may or may not be sure who they're talking to or why would be adding an unnecessary communication barrier, not to mention the possibility of obfuscating the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the number of times: there's no technical limit on the number of edits you can make. [Some posts have lots](http://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/231220/posts-with-the-most-revisions), which might alter your bar for "a fairly large edit history". Posts used to be automatically converted to community wiki after enough edits, but [that no longer happens ever](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/). The only real limit is that at revision #50, it might be healthier to let that post go in its imperfect state and turn your attention elsewhere.

So if you want to improve your post, go ahead, if you consider it a worthwhile improvement. That can include single word changes ([I have done that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/44476/revisions)) or big rewrites to communicate the same message better (see [revision #4](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/35571/revisions)). Rewrites for entertainment value is fine too, just make sure it's *good*, and aids communication, or at the very least, doesn't diminish it.

If you're trying to benignly rewrite your question, you may want to carefully avoid *breaking* existing answers with your changes - i.e. bringing your question to a state where they're not quite valid answers to it any longer. [That can be bad.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3117/1204) If that's a disconnect because you changed how you're asking your question, that might impair readability for visitors to the site. However, if you really did preserve the meaning of your question, it might simply be exposting an answer that wasn't solving your problem very effectively in the first place.